Fetch request is still cached by default in Next.js 15
According to the Next.js blog and documentation fetch requests are no longer cached by default since Next.js 15:
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-15
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch#optionscache
However, if I send the same request twice in a component, the second request is still cached.
To reproduce it I created a new Next.js app using npx create-next-app@latest (installs Next.js 15.0.4).
Then in src/app/page.tsx I added following function:
const getData = async () => {
  const before = Date.now();
  await fetch('https://www.somedomain.com');
  const after = Date.now();

  return after - before;
};

and calling this in the Home component:
export default async function Home() {
  const diff1 = await getData();
  const diff2 = await getData();

  return (
    <>
      <p>Fetch1 took {diff1}ms</p>
      <p>Fetch2 took {diff2}ms</p>
    </>
  );
}

This results in following output:
Fetch1 took 132ms
Fetch2 took 2ms

I expected Next.js 15 to not cache the second request.
It is mentioned here that 'no-store' is the default.
But even if I add { cache: 'no-store' } explicitly, the request will be cached:
await fetch('https://www.somedomain.com', { cache: 'no-store' });

Am I missing something?

The fetch options are for Data Caching, not for Memoization. React keeps the result of the fetch call during rendering. Since you're using it in a Page, the result is preserved throughout the rendering. In this situation, it seems that the lack of Data Caching is being blocked by the Memoization mechanism.
I suggest you also read this article
Request Memoization
